# How to Remove Ubuntu using windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I have a question!

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and windows 7 on my PC in dual-boot mode. Now, for some reasons, my Ubuntu is totally broken! When I try to boot Ubuntu, a terminal-like screen comes and the only thing I can do is typing some commands (and I don't know how to fix my Ubuntu using this screen).

So, I picked up my Ubuntu files using windows 7 (with this [tutorial](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-access-linux-files-in-windows-when-dual-booting-linux-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-windows-10-81)) and now I want to remove Ubuntu and install it from scratch. The only problem here is deleting my current Ubuntu (which doesn't work!)! When I insert a bootable disk of Ubuntu, it doesn't give me the option to re-install Ubuntu (seems that it doesn't identify the installed Ubuntu).

The only way I can think of, is deleting Ubuntu files From its partition on Windows 7. Does this solution work? Can Ubuntu be uninstalled with deleting its files using Windows?

Thank you!

Comment: You delete Ubuntu from the Live DVD is your intention is to re-install Ubuntu. Doing it from Windows is off-topic. And if it does not recognize your old install: did you boot with the same uefi method as it was installed? If not that would be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Back up your files.

Boot your machine up with the Ubuntu installation LiveDVD or usb stick and select install Ubuntu by doing "something else." This will bring up a list of the available disk partitions. Select the partition where your old Ubuntu installation resides. Click "Change." Make sure that the "Use as" and "mount point" fields are correct. These will likely be "ext-4 journaling" and "/" Click "OK." Click on the "format" checkbox. Click on "Install Now."

The installer should guide you through the rest of the installation process.